# Transpose Elements 2D SafeArray from Excel in C/C++ DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Excel VBA I can use `RtlCopyMemory` to move each element in a 2D SafeArray of Variants to another SafeArray of Variants in such a way that the elements are transposed.

The following VBA snippet works perfectly for this (assuming the variables have appropriate values):

```
For i = 0 To TotalElems - 1
    CopyMemory ByVal ptrDest + i * LenElem, ByVal ptrSrc + (Elems1D * col + row) * LenElem, LenElem
    col = col + 1
    If col = Elems2D Then
        col = 0
        row = row + 1
    End If
Next
```

However, I was disappointed by the speed of execution. The above snippet is about five times slower than simply using VBA to assign the values, one at a time, to the second array.

The arrays can be large; they can have many thousands of elements.

My guess is that the thousands of calls to `RtlCopyMemory` are expensive.

So I wanted to test if moving the above snippet to a C/C++ DLL and calling it once (instead of thousands of times) would eliminate the bottleneck and perhaps even be faster than assigning the values directly in VBA.

I am extremely rusty on C/C++ but managed the following. But it does not work. It does return the "1", and Excel does not crash. But the values in the destination array are undisturbed by the code. It's as if nothing happened at all.

```
long int __stdcall TransposeMemory(long *ptrDest, long *ptrSrc, long &LenElem, long &Elems1D, long &Elems2D, long &TotalElems) {

    long col = 0;
    long row = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < TotalElems; i++) {

        memcpy (&ptrDest + (i * LenElem), &ptrSrc + (Elems1D * col + row) * LenElem, LenElem);

        col++;
        if (col == Elems2D) {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }

    return 1; 
}
```

From VBA, I call it like this:

```
Result = TransposeMemory(array2(1, 1), array1(1, 1), LenElem, Elems1D, Elems2D, TotalElems)
```

Passing the arrays in this manner gives the C/C++ DLL function a pointer to the first element in each array. All of the data are stored contiguously and each element in 16 bytes in length.

Can you show me where I'm going wrong?

As a followup question, what method would accomplish this data transform the absolute quickest?

To help clarify the data layout, imagine a range of cells in Excel in rows and columns:

```
+---+---+---+
| a | e | i |
+---+---+---+
| b | f | j |
+---+---+---+
| c | g | k |
+---+---+---+
| d | h | l |
+---+---+---+
```

The above 2D array has four rows and three columns and Excel would display it on a worksheet in the above pattern.

However, VBA stores the values contiguously starting at the first element like this (with each element being 16 bytes in length):

```
+---+
| a |
+---+
| b |
+---+
| c |
+---+
| d |
+---+
| e |
+---+
| f |
+---+
| g |
+---+
| h |
+---+
| i |
+---+
| j |
+---+
| k |
+---+
| l |
+---+
```

When the data are transposed properly (and the VBA snippet at the top of this question does just that), Excel displays them like so:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
| e | f | g | h |
+---+---+---+---+
| i | j | k | l |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Notice that now we have three rows and four columns.

VBA stores the elements in the transposed array this order, which is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
+---+
| a |
+---+
| e |
+---+
| i |
+---+
| b |
+---+
| f |
+---+
| j |
+---+
| c |
+---+
| g |
+---+
| k |
+---+
| d |
+---+
| h |
+---+
| l |
+---+
```

Comment: `ptrDest` is already a pointer. I question the need to take the address of it in `memcpy (&ptrDest + (i * LenElem), ...)` ditto with `ptrSrc`. You are stunningly unfortunate that this is not causing a crash.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. I just tried removing the AMPERSANDS from the first two parameters in the memcpy call and that crashed Excel instantly.

Comment: The ampersands were definitely wrong, the code was marching around the stack smashing things right and left. Whatever's wrong once the ampersands are gone I'm not seeing. If you are writing this in Visual Studio you should be able to create a debug build, place a breakpoint at the start of the function, and attach the debugger to the excel process and start stepping to make sure the math is turning out the way it should. Note: flattening the 2D array to 1D can often be a huge performance gain even in C++.

Comment: Have a look at open source library (LibXL) to read/write from/to excel from c++.

Answer (score 0):

I see very strong performance difference on Office 64-bit between `RtlCopyMemory` and `RtlMoveMemory`, for Office 32-bit I can't tell, but it may still be relevant.
In many forums CopyMemory is defined as:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
```

This routine checks for overlapping memory parts of source and destination and seems to be much [slower on Office 64 than on Office 32](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?707879-VB6-Dereferencing-Pointers-sans-CopyMemory).
For coyping between two VBA variables you can safely use

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlCopyMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
```

This might solve your performance issue so that you don't need to use the workaround with C-code.

Comment: I need to apologise for not reading exactly. You already wrote explicitly that you are using `RtlCopyMemory`. I now did compare myself with Office 64-bit and found a difference of 50 between direct assignment and RtlCopyMemory. So it is even worse than your result. RtlMoveMemory is another order of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 0):

Second answer: We learned that Office is not brilliant in calling dlls, so why not using the fact that indexing is comparably fast:

The code below copies the data of an array `a` to an equally sized 2D typed array `a1` of the element size of variant (16 byte on 32-bit, 24 byte on 64-bit), transposes it to another typed array `b1` and copies the data back to `a`. After that the dimensions of `a` are switched by tweaking the safearray structure.
Note that this is better than copying it to another array `b`, as variants may contain strings, where only the pointer is stored in the block of array data. In case of copying variants by RtlCopyMemory, the string pointers of `b` point to the same memory and at the end of the program Excel tries to free the strings twice and might crash. If you are only copying numeric values than you are safe.
The attached routine is comparable in speed to direct assignment for numeric values but outperforms largely for string values :-)
And it solves the problem of redimensioning the original array.
(It could still be made faster by setting the datapointer of `a1` to the original values of `a`, but that's another potential source of memory errors.)

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Const PTR_LEN = 8
    Const VAR_LEN = 24
#Else
    Const PTR_LEN = 4
    Const VAR_LEN = 16
#End If

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlCopyMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub ZeroMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlZeroMemory" (hpvDest As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)

Private Type SAFEARRAYBOUND
    cElements    As Long
    lLbound      As Long
End Type

Private Type SafeArray
    cDims        As Integer
    fFeatures    As Integer
    cbElements   As Long
    cLocks       As Long
    pvData       As LongPtr
    bounds(1 To 2) As SAFEARRAYBOUND
End Type

Type hh
    a(1 To VAR_LEN) As Byte
End Type


Sub TransposeVariantArrayInPlace(ByRef a As Variant)
    Dim ptrSA As LongPtr, SA As SafeArray, bound As SAFEARRAYBOUND
    Dim aPtr As LongPtr, a1Ptr As LongPtr, b1Ptr As LongPtr, a1() As hh, b1() As hh
    Dim j1 As Long, j2 As Long, j3 As Long, m As Long, n As Long, Totalsize As LongPtr

    'retrieve the pointer to the safearray
    ptrSA = VarPtr(a) + 8
    CopyMemory ptrSA, ByVal ptrSA, PTR_LEN

    'copy the safearray data
    CopyMemory SA, ByVal ptrSA, LenB(SA)
    ' Exit if not a 2D array
    If SA.cDims <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    ' generate typed arrays of equal dimensions
    m = SA.bounds(2).cElements
    n = SA.bounds(1).cElements
    ReDim a1(1 To m, 1 To n)
    ReDim b1(1 To n, 1 To m)

    ' retrieve pointers to array data
    aPtr = VarPtr(a(1, 1))
    a1Ptr = VarPtr(a1(1, 1))
    b1Ptr = VarPtr(b1(1, 1))

    Totalsize = m * n * VAR_LEN

    ' Copy the content of a to a1 and store the transposed array in b1
    CopyMemory ByVal a1Ptr, ByVal aPtr, Totalsize
    For j1 = 1 To m
        For j2 = 1 To n
            b1(j2, j1) = a1(j1, j2)
        Next
    Next

    ' write the transposed values back to a
    CopyMemory ByVal aPtr, ByVal b1Ptr, Totalsize

    ' change the dimensions of a in the safearray structure
    bound = SA.bounds(1)
    SA.bounds(1) = SA.bounds(2)
    SA.bounds(2) = bound
    CopyMemory ByVal ptrSA, SA, LenB(SA)

    ' important to empty the arrays in the case that string values have been assigned
    ' because Excel would try to free the space twice and might crash
    ZeroMemory ByVal a1Ptr, Totalsize
    ZeroMemory ByVal b1Ptr, Totalsize
End Sub

Function Transpose(ByRef a As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ptrSA As LongPtr, SA As SafeArray, bound As SAFEARRAYBOUND
    Dim b As Variant, j1 As Long, j2 As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    'retrieve the pointer to the safearray
    ptrSA = VarPtr(a) + 8
    CopyMemory ptrSA, ByVal ptrSA, PTR_LEN

    'copy the safearray data
    CopyMemory SA, ByVal ptrSA, LenB(SA)
    ' Exit if not a 2D array
    If SA.cDims <> 2 Then Exit Function

    ' generate typed arrays of equal dimensions
    m = SA.bounds(2).cElements
    n = SA.bounds(1).cElements
    ReDim b(1 To n, 1 To m)

    For j1 = 1 To m
        For j2 = 1 To n
            b(j2, j1) = a(j1, j2)
        Next
    Next

    Transpose = b

End Function

Sub TransposeComparison()
    Dim a, b As Variant
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, j1 As Long, j2 As Long, t1, t2, t3

    m = 2000
    n = 1000
    ReDim a(1 To m, 1 To n) As Variant

    'Filling the area with some test data
    For j1 = 1 To m
        For j2 = 1 To n
            a(j1, j2) = CLngLng(10 * j1 + j2)
            'a(j1, j2) = CLngLng(10 * j1 + j2) & "HH" ' for string assisnments
        Next
    Next

    t1 = Timer()

    ' classical indexing
    b = Transpose(a)

    t2 = Timer()

    TransposeVariantArrayInPlace a

    t3 = Timer()

    MsgBox t2 - t1 & " " & t3 - t2

End Sub
```

P.S.: I edited the code for readibility.
Note that the array `a` has to be declared as `dim a` or `dim a as Variant`, otherwise `ReDim a(1 to m, 1 to n)` works but you need another `CopyMemory ptrSA, ByVal ptrSA, PTR_LEN` in order to retrieve the safearray pointer.